# How do you use IronRuby to print a report of public methods and public properties of a C# class?

Tags: ironruby

Does anyone have a code sample showing how you reflect upon a random c# class from an arbitrary .NET assembly using IronRuby?    I am most interested in listing the public methods and properties from a random C# class and .NET assembly.

I have tried to load "System.Reflection" from IronRuby.   I can't seem to find a good code sample for doing this.

I know that Ruby can explore the meta data related to a class as well.    I, however, can't seem to load my test assembly. (i.e. Test.dll)

Any help that you can offer would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to load your Test.dll you will just need to `require 'Test'` assuming its visible to your script.

You can use the built-in Ruby method `public_instance_methods` but this will include those from Ruby's Object class, e.g.:

```
System::String.public_instance_methods
```

If you are only interested in the methods of your CLR type then you can access the Type of a given object through the IronRuby `to_clr_type` method. This gives you access to all the reflection methods that System.Type offers. For example, the following script will list all the public instance methods of a class Test.MyClass in Test.dll:

```
$: << 'path/to/dll'

require 'Test'

puts Test::MyClass.to_clr_type.get_methods(
  System::Reflection::BindingFlags.Public | System::Reflection::BindingFlags.Instance | System::Reflection::BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
```

Comment: Just to add to this answer - the problem with using ironruby's metaprogramming capabilities for reflection-like operations is that ironruby changes the names of the properties and methods to meet the ruby standards (a process called "name mangling"). Therefore, a method named "DoThat" will turn out to be "do_that" inside IronRuby... So this is something to take into consideration.